# MIPS program is finished running (dropped off bottom) error

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, mars-simulator

It's my first time doing MIPS assembly and I'm trying to create a program that (1) accepts user's input (2) pre-store it in a specific address (3) multiply using repeated addition

Here's my program:

```
  #Data Segment#
  .data 0x10010000
  x: .word  1988
  y: .word  1923

  .text
   #Main Segment
   main:
    sub    $t3, $t3, $t3            #initialize counter
    sub    $t4, $t4, $t4            #initialize product
    multiloop:
        lui    $t0, 0x1001
        lw     $t1, 0($t0)  #load first integer value; variable for addition
        lw     $t2, 4($t0)  #load second integer value; variable for counter
          sub    $t2, $t2, $t3  #counter operation
          bltz   $t2, done      #if counter > 0 means operation is complete
          add    $t4, $t4, $t1  #addition
          addi   $t3, $t3, 1    #increment counter
        j multiloop     #loop
   done:
    sw  $t4, 32($t0)
```

The question is: why is my program " program is finished running (dropped off bottom)". Any help? Thanks!

Comment: It falls off the end because you branch out of the loop, and there's no exit system call after the `sw` instruction.  It's nice that your simulator tells you that instead of just faulting on bogus instructions from trying to decode+execute whatever padding / garbage next in memory like a real CPU would.  (Or faulting on instruction fetch if the last instruction was at the end of a page.)  Anyway, is that all you're asking?  Or are you asking why your loop isn't infinite?

Comment: I'm trying to make this program give me the output(of the multiplication of two inputs) but yeah so far I can't even give inputs because of the "program is finished running (dropped off bottom)" thing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean?  The inputs are assemble-time constants, so the program just runs and falls off the end (near-instantly because I think the loop doesn't have to run many iterations).  You didn't include any system calls for input or output, so if you want to observe anything you need to set a breakpoint or single-step.

Comment: in assembly the program does not end with end of source file, it "ends" when you either loop it into infinite loop, or in MARS there exists "exit" syscall service, to let MARS know your code did finish, use that one (v0 = 10: https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html ) (usually any decent example hello world has this one, so try to play with some working example in debugger, it will help you a lot later with your own problems)