# How do you add in mips?

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

First i know ive asked tons of questions but ive come a long way since i last asked.

Im using mars simulator for some side project learning.
Ive always been interested in assembly and mips is my choice.

Anyways my program seems to crash after i try and move my values and add them up and i cant figure out why.
Thanks for looking and tips will be great.
Have a good day

```
    .data
msg0: .asciiz "enter a number:  \n"
msg1: .asciiz "enter another number:  \n"
result: .asciiz "result is:  \n"

.text
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg0   #load first message
syscall

li $v0 5
move $t0, $v0  #user input
syscall         #store number


li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg1    #second msg
syscall

li $v0, 5
move $t1, $v0   #second input and store number
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, result  #rsult message
syscall

add $t3,$t1,$t0  #and my problem is here for some reason?
syscall
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553510/mips-program-is-finished-running-dropped-off-bottom-error

Comment: Also, the last `syscall` makes no sense. Adding two registers is not a system call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a label that are function names. In the code I have provided below, the function name is **main**. Also, the last system call serves no purpose now. What you need to do is indicate that your code has finished before making the last system call by **li $v0,10**.

```
    .data
    msg0: .asciiz "enter a number:  \n"
    msg1: .asciiz "enter another number:  \n"
    result: .asciiz "result is:  \n"

    .text
    .globl main

    main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, msg0   #load first message
    syscall

    li $v0 5
    syscall         
    move $t0, $v0  #first input and store number


    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, msg1    #second msg
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t1, $v0   #second input and store number

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, result  #result message
    syscall

    add $t3,$t1,$t0  

    move $a0, $t3    
    li $v0, 1        
    syscall     #print answer

    li $v0,10
    syscall
```